# Trying to direct a user to the next page when clicking the next button

Tags: django, url, view, slug

I have a app which is letting users fill in a few question, click a button to fill in a form with their contactinfo and redirecting them to a thank you page after submitting the form.

At first I had the error:

- Reverse for 'contact' with arguments '('',)' not found. *

So I set a get method with reverse_lazy. Now the error is gone but when I click the buttons it directs me back to the same page. Read the docs but cannot find out what is going wrong.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:bedrijfslug>/check', CheckView.as_view(), name='check'),
    path('<slug:bedrijfslug>/contact/', ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
]
```

views.py

```
class CheckView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'register/check.html'
    model = Bedrijf

    slug_url_kwarg = 'bedrijfslug'

    context_object_name = 'bedrijf'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwars):
        contact_url = reverse_lazy('ContactView')
        return render(request, 'register/check.html', {'contact_url': contact_url})

class ContactView(FormView):
    template_name = 'register/contact.html'
    form_class = BezoekerForm
    success_url = '/thankyou/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to reference the slug field in my view. This method did the trick:

```
def bedrijf_detail(self, slug):
    bedrijf = Bedrijf.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(self, {'bedrijf': bedrijf})
```